# Matching with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, constraints

For fun, I'm creating a program that generates partners for a Secret Santa gift exchange. However, in this setup, instead of randomly generating pairs, constraints are allowed.

Example: Person A and Person B hate each other, so neither A nor B should be assigned to buy a gift for the other.

Second Example: Person C bought a gift for Person D last year. Person C should not be assigned to buy a gift for Person D, but person D should still be allowed to buy C a gift.

In general, I want to generate a bijective function from a set to itself, but that function needs to be sensitive to constraints. If there are too many constraints such that the problem can't be solved, the routine should return an error or something.

This looks to me like some sort of graph problem, but I don't really know what direction to go in to solve it. How can I solve this problem programmatically? Are there existing algorithms I can use/modify?

Comment: @Bunyip: it's an algorithmic question, SSCCE have nothing to do with this perfectly fine question.

Comment: @Bunyip Reasons concerning questions concerning problems with code that's been written needs to be attached to questions concerning problems with code that's been written. "Questions asking for code ..." would probably make sense, except that that reason is ... just wrong (in general). You can probably make an argument for downvoting the question.

Comment: @Bunyip: she's not asking for code, she's asking for an idea. Did you ever saw an abstract representation of an algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially your problem is well-known [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem):

Consider a bipartite graph where each side has all persons as nodes (yes, each person will appear twice: once at the left side and once at the right one). Then you can add an edge from person A from the left side to the right side's person B if A is allowed to send a gift to B. Then you can apply, for example, [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find assignment which maximizes number of allowed gifts.

[image: Bipartite graph]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "maximizes number of allowed gifts" - can you please rephrase that?
Also, do I need a bipartite graph? Or can I have a directed graph where each person is represented by one node and the arrow represents if the first node can give the second node a gift. Then, can I search for a path that hits every node to find a valid solution? Is that a legitimate way to attack this problem?

Comment: By "maximizes number of allowed gifts" mean assignment that maximizes number of pairs. For example, is there are 4 persons A, B, C, D and A can send gift to C and D, while B can send gift only to D. So if A send gift to D, then B wouldn't pair with anybody.

Comment: @Michelle, will your approach work in case when all constraints can't be satisfied? This one will. I'm not sure if you can safely get rid of bipartite graph, it could depend on particular algorithm.

Comment: @Michelle: that approach fails even when there are feasible solutions. Consider e.g. a case where you have A, B, C, D: A and B can make gifts one each other, and the same for C and D. This scenario has a solution (A <-> B and C <-> D), but does not have an eulerian cycle (in fact, the graph has two disconnected components). Looks like you need to have bipartite graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [constraint Satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).
There is a graphical representation for the problem, that shows visually how it is solved. 
I took a course on AI that talked about  it.  Here is a lecture slides:
[Lecture](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs486/lecture4.pdf).  Slide 15 shows the picture. 
Read through the slides, there are several algorithms that solve CSP, including Variable Elimitation ( slide 44).

---

Comment: Using general approaches to CSP for such a tiny and standard problem is waaaay overkill.